# If controller in While controller in JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter, load-testing

I am using JMeter for load testing. My requirement is to make request till server does not give 200 as status code. And if status code is other than 200 then wait for 5 sec and retry again. To wait for 5 sec I have taken constatnt timer. My problem is constatnt timer in if controller is not working. What could be the solution? I have attached snapshot of jmeter window.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have ended up with BeansShellTimer Script with [this example](http://ideoplex.com/id/1374/beanshell-timer-in-jmeter).

Answer (score 0):

Putting the constant timer as the only child in an if controller makes no sense. Timers work as pre-processors for samplers in JMeter.

So please put your timer as a child of the sampler.